# AppleStore App Review Issues for cross platform app

Tags: ios, watchkit, siri

> TMS-90496: Invalid Executable - The executable 'AppName.app/Watch/OBDXWatchApp.app/PlugIns/OBDXWatchAppExtension.appex/OBDXWatchAppExtension' does not contain bitcode.
>
> ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - No identifier was provided a vocabulary concept with language "English". Please refer to 'https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit'
>
> ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - No intent parameters specified for bundle "com.abc.xyz" language "English" vocabulary policy #1
>
> Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to make you aware of them:
>
> ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - No vocabulary examples were submitted for vocabulary item "" in the "English" language

Can someone please help me resolve these issues? Localization is already defined in my project's AppIntentvocabulary.plist and SiriKitExtension info.plist files.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @NimeshNeema how to resolve these issues, as localization is already defined in appintentvoca....plist file